# How to hide an element using useState and classList manipulation - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, use-state

I am trying to create a way of toggling on and off certain elements of an svg that is being used across a design, so it is reusable across the website.

To be more specific I am trying to create a toggle that will hide the red line part of the svg by entering "false" into the setter prop - so across the project this can be done where needed.

I am using useState and a sort of props system to try and achieve this however I am having trouble around the specifics - the current error I get is "ReferenceError: setter is not defined".

Is there a better way to achieve this? and what way would I go about it so setter is defined and my current approach would work?

Code below:

```
const LineSvg = ({setter, toggle}) => {


    return(
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 59.6 830" xmlSpace="preserve" className="capsules capsules-image-bottom-right position-absolute">
            <path id="red-line" toggle={toggle} setter={setter}  className="capsule-a capsule-foreground fill-red track-on-scroll" d="M10.4,257.6A10.39,10.39,0,0,1,20.8,268V584.4a10.4,10.4,0,0,1-20.8,0V267.9A10.37,10.37,0,0,1,10.4,257.6Z" />
            <g className="track-on-scroll">
                <path id="green-line"   d="M49.2,394.7a10.39,10.39,0,0,1,10.4,10.4v84.4a10.4,10.4,0,0,1-20.8,0V405.1A10.33,10.33,0,0,1,49.2,394.7Z" className="capsule-b fill-green" />
                <path id="blue-line"    d="M49.2,354.6A10.39,10.39,0,0,1,59.6,365v4.9a10.4,10.4,0,1,1-20.8,0v-5A10.31,10.31,0,0,1,49.2,354.6Z" className="capsule-c fill-blue" />
                <path id="grey-line"    d="M49.2,235.2a10.39,10.39,0,0,1,10.4,10.4V330a10.4,10.4,0,0,1-20.8,0V245.6a10.33,10.33,0,0,1,10.4-10.4Z" className="capsule-d fill-grey-light" />
            </g>
        </svg>
    )
}

export default LineSvg;
```

index.jsx

```
const HomePage = () => {

    const [redToggle, setRedToggle] = useState(true);

    if(setter == "false"){
        setRedToggle(false)
    } else if(setter == "true"){
        setRedToggle(true)
    }

    const onToggle = () => {
        const redLine = document.getElementById("red-line");

        if(redToggle === false){
            redLine.classList.add("capsule-hide")
        } else if(redToggle === true){
            redLine.classList.remove("capsule-hide")
        }
    }

    

    return(
        
        <Layout>
            <Hero  
                text={
                    <h1>If your software goals aren't ambitous, don't bother scrolling.</h1>
                }
                image={
                    //If nothing is to go in here empty "" needed to prevent error
                    ""
                }
            />

           
            <section className="dark-grey-section py-10">
                <Container>
                    <Row>
                        <Col sm={12} md={6}>
                            <div className="text-column">
                                <h5>What we do</h5>
                                <h4><strong>Thrive in the era of software advantage</strong></h4>
                                <p>Today’s users aren’t easily impressed.</p>
                                <p>And what it does take to impress them can be insanely difficult to build.</p>
                                <p>Insanely difficult happens to be our speciality.</p>
                                <p>Lineate helps businesses craft the software that fits their ambitious needs—quickly, reliably and future-proofed. </p>
                                <a className="btn" href="#">Learn more about our ethos</a>
                            </div>
                        </Col>
                        <Col sm={12} md={6}>
                            <div className="position-relative">
                                <CapsuleSvg image="images/2-young-men-looking-at-a-desktop-computer-in-an-office.jpg" setter="false" toggle={onToggle}/>
                                <LineSvg/>
                            </div>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Container>
            </section>

        </Layout>
        
    )
}

export default HomePage;
```

Comment: can you post a codesandbox?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/live/f98f2224291 here is one although no styles in it

Comment: `setter` is not defined anywhere in `Home` component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like adding a prop which would look like this..

Small change in your LineSvg

```
const LineSvg = ({redLineActive}) => {


    return(
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 59.6 830" xmlSpace="preserve" className="capsules capsules-image-bottom-right position-absolute">
    {redLineActive ?
            <path id="red-line" className="capsule-a capsule-foreground fill-red track-on-scroll" d="M10.4,257.6A10.39,10.39,0,0,1,20.8,268V584.4a10.4,10.4,0,0,1-20.8,0V267.9A10.37,10.37,0,0,1,10.4,257.6Z" /> 
    : null }
            <g className="track-on-scroll">
                <path id="green-line"   d="M49.2,394.7a10.39,10.39,0,0,1,10.4,10.4v84.4a10.4,10.4,0,0,1-20.8,0V405.1A10.33,10.33,0,0,1,49.2,394.7Z" className="capsule-b fill-green" />
                <path id="blue-line"    d="M49.2,354.6A10.39,10.39,0,0,1,59.6,365v4.9a10.4,10.4,0,1,1-20.8,0v-5A10.31,10.31,0,0,1,49.2,354.6Z" className="capsule-c fill-blue" />
                <path id="grey-line"    d="M49.2,235.2a10.39,10.39,0,0,1,10.4,10.4V330a10.4,10.4,0,0,1-20.8,0V245.6a10.33,10.33,0,0,1,10.4-10.4Z" className="capsule-d fill-grey-light" />
            </g>
        </svg>
    )
}

export default LineSvg;
```

Then in your index you could do something like this. Im not sure how you plan on toggling it so adjust to how you plan to toggle it.

```
...
const [redToggle, setRedToggle] = useState(true);
...
return (
...
<LineSvg redLineActive={redToggle}/>
<button onClick={() => setRedToggle(!redToggle}>Toggle</button>
...
```

There are some other ways to do it if you want multiple red line svg's but let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I do this approach with user interactive stuff - however this is more for devs. In the sense when building this website I just want to be able to toggle aspects of the svg on and off - but I do not want a button where the user would do this. This is only to make the build easier and more efficient.

Comment: So that is why I was thinking of using some sort of props system?

Comment: @MichaelStubbs what is your condition to toggle the red line? You can still useState just have something else than controls the state

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly by condition? But yes I would still most likely use useState, I just want to toggle it on and off around the design where it is not there. It is essentially one SVG we are using made up of multiple components(lines) which we want to toggle and off across design as the SVG is used differently across the website to achieve different looks. So it would be devs toggling it on and off where it fits design. No user interaction.

Comment: @MichaelStubbs Then instead of having <LineSvg redLineActive={redToggle}/> you could just do <LineSvg redLineActive={false}/> or <LineSvg redLineActive={true}/>